# I need some formal ways of saying, "some people were responsible for the failure"

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary, phrase-request

**Context:**

> There were once 15 workers in our shop.
> Some weeks ago, the boss of our shop received an important order from the customer, Paul (nickname).
> We were told that Paul wanted to hold an important ceremonial dinner for 50 people in three days.
> (Each night there would be 50 people, and the dinner would be held in three evenings in a row)
>   Then the 15 workers were divided into three groups (each group consisted of 1 Chef and 4 assistants).
> Each group was asked to make 50 main dishes and 50 desserts
>   But some problem happened on the third day. Group C could not finish the dishes and desserts on time and ruined the dinner.
>   Our boss was very unhappy, and the five workers in group C were fired.

Given that situation, is it a formal way to use *responsible for* in this sentence:

> Five people were *responsible for* the failure of the dinner, and so dismissed from their posts.

If not, is it better to replace *responsible for* with *accountable for*?

Comment: You started building a story and reading it, at first, I thought it's some math question! Actually, looking at the question in the end, I would not expect the story to be explained at all! Do I consider that your question is simple: Which one is better? Someone 'responsible/accountable' for some failure? And in any case, [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63958/difference-between-accountability-and-responsibility) and [this](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Accountability_vs_Responsibility) could be very useful.

Comment: ***Five people were held accountable for failure of the given task and so were dismissed from their posts.*** It could be right?

Comment: maybe I forgot "the" before "failure," or it could be just me. :)

Comment: Thanks Maulik V. Hi Usernew, please post your comment as an answer. I want to give yours a vote up.

Comment: Depending on the problem, scapegoated might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original sentence:

> Five people were responsible for the failure of the dinner, and so dismissed from their posts.

I would advice you to drop the comma as it is irrelevant in your sentence and add the be verb: **were**.

The verbs have to agree. In the first clause, five people ***were held***, and so in the second clause the verb must follow the same tense, ***were dismissed.***

**Try:**

> Five people were held accountable for the failure of the given task and so were dismissed from their posts.

Or

> Five people were held accountable for failing at their given task and were dismissed from their posts.

---

From [Diffen.com](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Accountability_vs_Responsibility):

> .....Accountability is something you hold a person to **only after a task is done or not done.** Responsibility can be **before and/or after a task.**

From [a similar question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63967/124070):

> You TAKE responsibility and you are HELD accountable.

---

Read more about verbs [here](http://www.towson.edu/ows/tenseconsistency.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The briefest is often the best:

*Five people responsible for the failure were fired.*

This sentence leaves out "who were" after "people" -- a common way of keeping sentences brief. I use *fired* rather than dismissed to be clear that they lost their jobs, not just an assignment or rank.